# DB2 SQL Statement WHERE clause CASE WHEN in multiple conditions

Tags: sql, select, db2

This is what I am trying to do:

```
SELECT 
    id, name 
FROM 
    users 
WHERE 
    isActive=true
    (AND CASE WHEN {param} != null THEN name={param} ELSE null END)
```

if the passed `{param}` is not null then only the `AND` operator will be added otherwise just `isActive=true` condition will be used.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT 
    id, name 
FROM 
    users 
WHERE 
    isActive=true
 AND (({param} is not null AND name={param}) OR ({param} is null))
```

Comment: || is the CONCAT operator in standard SQL, use OR instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like COALESCE or (in case of DB2) NVL.

```
SELECT 
    id, name 
FROM 
    users 
WHERE 
    isActive=true
    AND name=COALESCE({param},name)
```

You didn't say how you pass parameters/variables, so i'll leave it to you. "{param}" could be replaced with a column or constant in this example

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: COALESCE works well with Db2 (at least with LUW)

Comment: @Lennart yes, COALESCE is standard SQL and works with DB2. I prefer NVL but it's not available for all databases

Comment: Ah, I misread you. I thought you meant that COALESCE where not available in Db2